# Bash Script not parsed correctly

Tags: linux, bash

I have a Shell Script that I want to run on Linux.

When I run it manually line by line, it works as desired. But when I put the Code into a File (`unbound_update.sh`) and assign proper chmod (chmod +x) permissions, I recieve following error during execution:

```
unbound_update.sh: 6: [[: not found
Download of unbound_ad_servers list failed!
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3311  100  3311    0     0  11148      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11148
unbound_update.sh: 25: [[: not found
Download of unbound root.hints failed!
```

It seems to me, that Bash does not parse the script correctly.

My Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Updating Unbound resources.
# Place this into e.g. /etc/cron.monthly or /etc/cron.weekly
###[ unbound_ad_servers ]###
curl -sS -L --compressed "http://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?hostformat=unbound&showintro=0&mimetype=plaintext" > /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers.new
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  mv /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers.bak
  mv /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers.new /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers
  unbound-checkconf >/dev/null
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    rm /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers.bak
    service unbound reload >/dev/null
  else
    echo "Warning: Errors in unbound configuration due to probably failed update of"
    echo "/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers:"
    unbound-checkconf
    mv /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers.new
    mv /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers.bak /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/unbound_ad_servers
  fi
else
  echo "Download of unbound_ad_servers list failed!"
fi
###[ root.hints ]###
curl -o /etc/unbound/root.hints.new https://www.internic.net/domain/named.cache
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  mv /etc/unbound/root.hints /etc/unbound/root.hints.bak
  mv /etc/unbound/root.hints.new /etc/unbound/root.hints
  unbound-checkconf >/dev/null
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    rm /etc/unbound/root.hints.bak
    service unbound reload >/dev/null
  else
    echo "Warning: Errors in newly downloaded root.hints file probably due to incomplete download:"
    unbound-checkconf
    mv /etc/unbound/root.hints /etc/unbound/root.hints.new
    mv /etc/unbound/root.hints.bak /etc/unbound/root.hints
  fi
else
  echo "Download of unbound root.hints failed!"
fi
```

Comment: How do you execute your script in your terminal ?

Comment: And what shell did you use to execute it line by line?

Comment: That error message looks like what the dash shell would print, not bash. Are you running this with the `sh` command (which overrides the shebang, and hence may run it in a shell other than bash)?

Comment: I am using Bash inside Debian and execute the Script with `sh`

Comment: run `./unbound_update.sh` instead

Comment: Tangentially, see also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)